# HTML / CSS - Tree Layout / Flowchart Options

Tags: html, css, drawing, flowchart

I have looked at the available libraries that are available and none seem to do exactly what I want.

I want to be able to produce a tree layout/flow chart which is horizontal.

Here is a very basic image:
[image]

Each box will have a parent and it needs to be able to flow automatically as I provide the data.

Another sample is this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic layouts is a strong domain of the (commercial) [yFiles Graph Drawing Libraries](http://www.yworks.com/).

Specifically [yFiles for HTML](http://www.yworks.com/yfileshtml) provides the feature you are looking for in the browser:

- You can customize the layout - in your case I suggest to use `GenericTreeLayouter` with `layoutOrientation` set to `LEFT_TO_RIGHT` and with a socalled `DefaultNodePlacer` configured for your nodes. Set the `rootAlignment` to `LEADING` and configure the preferred routing style. ([documentation](http://docs.yworks.com/yfileshtml/developers-guide/cls_GenericTreeLayouter.html))
- You can incrementally add new elements to the graph and have it animate smoothly
- You can style the visualization to your exact requirements.

I believe [this interactive demo](http://live.yworks.com/yfiles-for-html/1.2/demos/complete/demo.yfiles.graph.collapse/index.html) shows many of the requirements, but there are also [more complex](http://live.yworks.com/yfiles-for-html/1.2/demos/complete/demo.yfiles.graph.bpmneditor/index.html) demos that show the flow-charting aspect of your question.

<sup>Disclosure: I work for the company that creates that library, but I do not represent my employer on SO. My posts and thoughts are my own.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at the following libraries:

1. [JSPlumb](https://github.com/sporritt/jsPlumb)

   - This has a hierarchy option that I think is what you're looking for. Here is the [Demo](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demo/chart/dom.html).
2. [mxgraph](http://www.jgraph.com/mxgraph.html)

Answer (score 0):

that's a screenshot of [pyhole](https://github.com/raylu/pyhole)!

That was done using [KineticJS](https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/), a defunct project that provides abstraction on top of HTML canvas. Each oval was positioned manually/absolutely by doing a little math on the layout of the map/chain.